# Where can I get these data?

Tags: data

[image]

Look at this, I want to find such data, but I found Wolfram doesn't have.
  May I use other code?

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue might be that "Chinese" is the overall language, but the data is only available by dialect. I don't know if "dialects" is the proper term for that, but there seems to be data available if you only look at Mandarin, rather than Chinese as a whole.

Try:

```
LanguageData["ChineseMandarin", "CountryLanguageFractions"]
```

or

```
LanguageData["PanjabiEastern", "CountryLanguageFractions"]
```

yields:

[image: Results of LanguageData on other languages.]